# JavaFx can't get the node coordinate relative to scene

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

My code:

```
Button btn1 = new Button("Button");
    Button btn2 = new Button("The second Button");


    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn1,btn2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 300);

    System.out.println(btn2.getBoundsInLocal());
    System.out.println(btn2.getBoundsInParent());
    System.out.println(btn2.getLayoutBounds());
    System.out.println(btn2.layoutBoundsProperty());
```

Print:

```
BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]
BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]
BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]
ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: Button@5f3c42b9[styleClass=button]'The second Button', name: layoutBounds, value: BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]]
```

My question is: When I get the coordinate of btn1, the MinX and MinY is 0, I can understand. but about btn2, the MinY should not be 0; and MaxX and MaxY also should not be 0. So how can I get the real coordinate of the left corner of the button in the VBox.   To be clear, I need the coordinate of the node which is relative to VBox. Thanks.

Comment: Move your `System.out.println()` statements after `primaryStage.show()`.

Comment: Size and position are assigned during a layout pass, which has not happened in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to get the parent bounds and then specify what you want relative to those.

```
System.out.println(btn2.getBoundsInParent().getY());
System.out.println(btn2.getBoundsInParent().getX());
```